# Multiple listview.builder methods in single container

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to show few listviews in the same body container. I'm using Listview.builder because i have to fetch json data and display in a listview.

Each listview have to fetch data from different json files and display below the previous listview vertically(yes like in nested listview).

I have seen nested listvie examples but. Is it possible to do with listview.builder ? If  so please show me  example or a tutorial link. Thank You!

This is the code I'm use to create the listview.

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: recent == null ? 0 : recent.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Image.network(recent[index]["_embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["source_url"]),
                    new Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: new ListTile(
                        title: new Padding(
                             padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0), 
                             child: new Text(recent[index]["title"]["rendered"])),
                        subtitle: new Text(
                           recent[index]["excerpt"]["rendered"].replaceAll(new RegExp(r'<[^>]*>'), '')
                       ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      )        
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `SliverList` with `SliverChildBuilderDelegate`:

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          // First JSON
        },
        childCount: childCount,
      ),
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          // Second JSON
        },
        childCount: childCount,
      ),
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          // Third JSON
        },
        childCount: childCount,
      ),
    ),
    ),
  ],
);
```